# SQL update all fields based on Join Model

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got two tables in Postgres:

```
Sources [id, term, type]
Posts   [id, source_id, message, term, type]
```

I'm de-normalizing this data, so I'm adding the term and type columns to each of the posts, and getting rid of the Sources table.

Is there a way to do a FAST query that update the Posts with each of their respective sources data (there are about 8 million posts).

Something like:

```
UPDATE posts
JOIN sources
ON posts.source_id = sources.id
SET post.term = sources.term,
    posts.term_type = sources.term_type;
```

But that is throwing a syntax error for me.

Comment: I think you miss the part where you change `posts` structure? because your `post` definition doesn't have `term` or `term_type` fields. And `source` doesnt exist in any table

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza true! I have updated.

Comment: Good I update my answer too :)

Comment: Don't denormalise.If you want something to be FAST, something else is probably wrong. Seek help.

Comment: @wildplasser I dont see that as denormailze, looks like he is just putting together related data to fix a previous design error. And he doesnt have problem with speed other than performing the update.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax in Postgres is:

```
UPDATE posts
    SET posts.source = sources.source,
        post.term = sources.term,
        posts.term_type = sources.term_type
    FROM sources
    WHERE posts.source_id = sources.id;
```

Or, you can use a row constructor:

```
UPDATE posts
    SET (source, term, term_type) = (select s.source, s.term, s.term_type
                                     from source s
                                     where posts.source_id = s.id
                                    );
```

Comment: Excellent! Which one of these will be faster?

Comment: @goddamnyouryan . . . I imagine the performance would be similar.  The second will return an error if more than one row matches (which is probably a good thing).

Answer (score 1):

In postgres each update consist on one `insert` and one `delete`. So beside double work also have impact if the index are active.

If you want update the **whole** table usually is much faster just create the table with the new values

```
CREATE TABLE post2 AS
    SELECT p.id, p.source_id, p.message, s.term, s.term_type.
    FROM posts p
    INNER JOIN source s
       ON p.source_id = s.id;
```

Then use `ALTER` to rename the `tablename` and create the proper index.

Comment: And what about index and constraints on old table? Recreate them each time?

Comment: @HAYMbl4 yes. recreated to match old table. But again we are talking of one in a blue moon operation not for daily maintenace. But when a create table take seconds and update take hours is better just work a litle more and build a script to do the updates and handling the create constrains index part.

Comment: If for columns involved in the condition create `index` (in this query they are `posts.source_id` and `source.id`) update will be fast. It is actual for `oracle` and big data in updation table. I think that for `postgrate` also

Comment: @HAYMbl4 if you want update a few rows is ok, The index make it real fast. But if you want update the whole table. Is much faster just create the new table with the right values.